# How to make a directed graph symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-difference, sparse-matrix, graph-theory

Say I have a directed graph given as an adjacency matrix $A$ in [CSR format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format)) represented by the arrays `ia` (row indexes) and `ja` (column indexes).
In my application the graph serves as the underlying spatial connectivity for an [RBF-FD](https://github.com/treverhines/RBF) discretization of a PDE. The graph originates from finding the $N$-nearest neighbor stencil for each node $\boldsymbol{x}_i$ of a $d$-dimensional point cloud.

For some purposes it is benefical to use symmetric stencils $S$, meaning that $\boldsymbol{x}_j \in S(\boldsymbol{x}_i)$ implies $\boldsymbol{x}_i \in S(\boldsymbol{x}_j)$ for all $i,j$ (or at least for interior nodes). This corresponds to making the directed graph symmetric (undirected). One example of where this is needed is in the METIS partitioning library, which expects graphs to be symmetric. Similarly, the Reverse Cuthill McKee ordering algorithm also expects a symmetric matrix.

**Question:** Given an adjacency matrix in CSR format as arrays `ia` and `ja`, how can I find the symmetric graph adjacency matrix arrays `ias`, `jas`?

I have noted in Scipy, the way they achieve this is by forming the matrix $A + A^T$ (see Scipy source [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_reordering.pyx)). Note that I don't want to compute the actual matrix values, but only the structure of the resulting matrix.

Is there any other way to achieve this, apart from the naive way of of initializing $M$ empty adjacency lists (for all $M$ nodes of my point cloud), iterating through all the nodes, and pushing each connection $(i,j)$ into the right list? It seems kind of unneccesary to process each connection twice.

Comment: The issue, of course, is that if you want to symmetrize the sparsity pattern, you don't yet know how many entries you need in each row. So you can't allocate the `ias` and `jas` arrays up front because you don't know how many entries they are going to have. Some kind of temporary storage is going to be necessary.

Comment: Assuming I find the transpose of $A^T$ and store it in arrays in `ib` and `jb`, I can find the size of `jc` (equal to number of non-zero elements in $C = A+A^T$) by passing through all of the rows and counting the number of common elements in `ja` and `jb` using a switch array, effectively populating the `ic` array. However, it might be better to use some estimate for the size of `jc` (knowing that the degrees of my nodes are roughly equal) and also store the column indices with one pass.

Comment: I have looked into the work of [Davis](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898718881). The sparse matrix addition is actually recast as a multiplication $C = \alpha A + \beta B = [A \; B][\alpha I \; \beta I]^T$. The matrix C is allocated with storage of size `anz + bnz`, and then the extra workspace is freed upon finishing.